# How does FireBase detect the existence of an user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

Let say that we have a million users registered in an app that uses Firebase Authe, so when a user log in, how this process works? Because is needed to use his Unique Id, so, how does Google check if that Id exists? Because it cannot realize an intelligent search by index, so it just checks one by one?

Comment: The existence of the user where? In Cloud Storage?

Comment: I edited the question @AlexMamo I mean, the FireBase Auth service

Comment: If by unique id, you mean their User Id, that something that is part of the Auth variable that's populated when the user authenticates. e.g. user enters user name and password and authenticates, the function that does that returns with a response from the server with either that the auth failed or if it succeeded, the auth var will be populated. It's pretty well covered in the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) - is there something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Google check if that ID exists?

It doesn't. If you need to check if a particular ID already exists, you have to check that. There is no need to check by default if an ID exists since Firebase Auth IDs are unique.

**Edit:**

> I couldn't understand Alex, let says that a user has an id of "123456", so when a User logs in to have access to his info, does not Google auth have to check if this user Id is in the database?

Firebase authentication is **not** related to any database. If you saved in the authentication process user data into a database as Cloud Firestore or the Realtime Database, and if you want later on to check if a particular ID already exists, you have to write code for that.

Comment: I couldn't understand Alex, let says than an user have an id of "123456", so when an Users logs in to have acces to his info, does not Google auth have to check if this user Id it is in the database (of thousand or millions of IdUsers) and when it found check if the password entered matches with the one of the database?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ok Alex, sorry the late reply, but then the FireBase Auth needs to access to some database to check if the users exist right? In any case, the final task that it needs to be done by, lets suppose, Cloud Firestore, is check user by user, if the Id matches with the storages one, right? Then if had a million users, then that wouln't be an slow task?

Comment: No, it won't be slow. The query performance in Firestore depends on the number of documents you request and not on the number of documents you search. It doesn't really matter if you search 1 document in a collection of 1.000 documents or in a collection that contains 100 MIL documents, the response time will always be the same.